# Initializing C structure that is an index of an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int number;
} Customer;
```

I also have an array of Customer structures.  I would like to initialize each index of the array with a Customer structure containing a name and a number.  Here is the code for that:

```
Customer* customerArray = malloc (5 * sizeof(Customer));
customerArray[0] = { "Name", 1 };
```

I'm getting a compiler error that says "Expected expression" and nothing else.  This happens for each array index that I try to initialize in this way.  However, if I do this:

```
Customer myCustomer = { "Name", 1 };
```

I do not get a compiler error.  Why do I only get this error when I try to initialize a structure that's in an array?

Comment: Is `name` supposed to be mutable or immutable?  That is, will you really point to a string literal or will you, for example, ask the user his name and than write it to `name`?  If you will be using the second option you need to allocate memory for `name` as well.

Comment: Should be mutable so that I don't have to initialize on the same line I declare

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This syntax is not valid:

```
customerArray[0] = { "Name", 1 };
```

Because this is not an initialization but an assignment, and a braced set of values can only be used when initializing.

You can either set each field individually:

```
customerArray[0].name = "Name";
customerArray[0].number = 1;
```

Or you can do the assignment with a compound literal:

```
customerArray[0] = (Customer){ "Name", 1 };
```

Comment: I'd recommend using designated initializers:
`customerArray[0] = (Customer){ .name =  "Name", .number = 1 };`